# Cocoapods circular dependency issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've installed the new cocoapods-0.35.0.rc2, and since that moment my project got totally messed up. I installed it by doing: '*sudo gem install cocoapods --pre*' immediately afterwards I've updated the libraries by doing: '*pod install*'. 

**However since that moment I receive the same error in the terminal: '*There is a circular dependency between XMPPFramework/Core and XMPPFramework/Authentication*'**
[image]

This error did not appear in the past and no matter what I try:

1. Installing cocoapods-0.34.4 instead of cocoapods-0.35.0.rc2
2. Removing XMPPFramework from the Podfile.
3. Removing all the files from the Podfile.
4. Cleaning the project
5. Deleting the content of the DerivedData
6. Discard all changes... and getting back to the version that used to work.

None of the above helped, I am quite sure that it is not directly related to the XMPPFramework as it did not have any new release lately.

Does anyone know how to solve such situations?

Thanks!

Comment: For #2 and #3, did you run pod update after removing the items from the podfile? If so, did you verify that the pods were actually removed from your workspace?

Comment: I didn't, and from your question I understand that I might be missing an important part of how cocoapod work, because I thought that 'pod install' updates the libraries

Comment: You didn't write that you ran `pod install` after steps 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this spec currently has circular dependency issues. This issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/pull/12783) for all the specs that have similar issues.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to bypass this issues temporarily in my code until it is fixed?

Comment: I don't believe so. Unless you could exclude the subspecs that are causing the issue. So if you need to whole library probably not. But luckily since I posted this about 20 of those have been fixed so hopefully it will be soon.

Answer (score 9):

Installation of cocoapods 0.34.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: first: sudo gem uninstall cocoapods, then: sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.34.1

Answer (score 2):

Until it's fixed you can remove XMPPFramework by removing it from the Podfile and running `pod update`, not `pod install`.

Answer (score 2):

For your information, the XMPPFramework pod's has been updated to fix the circular dependency issue and now support Swift as well.

Just add `pod 'XMPPFramework'` to your `Podfile`